# Data Processing in urban design

Tags: data-processing-vehicles

Can we patent integrated business processes combined and rearranged into a single business process flow?

Comment: This is an interesting question. My understanding is that business methods aren't patentable, but I'd prefer one of the actual patent attorneys to weight in.

Comment: Two comments: (1) The question is too vague for me to answer.  (2) "Can we patent X" is often the wrong question.  A better question is "Can we get valuable claims for X."

Comment: I believe, business methods are patentable. That is. New processes of achieving an outcome.